# "with which platform" vs. "on which platform"

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language

One of my friend invited me to watch a TV show together.

> A: "I'm going to watch endless Friends marathons this weekend. Would you join me?"

> I: "**on which platform**?"

> A: "Netflix"

Should I have said "**with which platform**"?

Are there any other expressions more natural could be used here?

Answer (score 2):

A "platform" is literally something one *stands on*. In this context, we still use "on" to describe the content on a streaming platform. But even leaving this very recent terminology aside, idiomatically, we have always said that we watch things "*on* television", **not** "*with*" television.

If you are looking for something more *natural*, I would say that the word "platform" is not used that much in casual contexts. Though widely understood, it is still really technical terminology.

I think the most natural responses would probably be "what shall we watch it on?", or simply "what on?". You could also ask "on Netflix?" which would elicit either a confirmation or a different answer.

Comment: Or just "what on?"